# при клику к блоку приминяется стиль js

Tags: javascript

```js
let table = document.getElementById('tableS');

let selectedTd;

table.onclick = function (event) {
    let target = event.target;

    while (target != this) {
        if (target.tagName == 'img') {
            highlight(target);
            return;
        }
        target = target.parentNode;
    }
}

function highlight(node) {
    if (selectedTd) {
        selectedTd.classList.remove('highlight');
    }
    selectedTd = node;
    selectedTd.classList.add('highlight');
}
```

```css
#tableS th {
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: bold;
}

#tableS td {
    width: 150px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: bottom;
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-bottom: 12px;
}

#tableS .highlight {
    opacity: 1;


}
h1, p{
    text-align:center;
}
img.animate {
    opacity: 0.25;
}
img.animate:hover {
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>task6</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="task1.css">
</head>
<body>

<table id="tableS">
    <tr>
        <td class="n">
            <img class="animate" src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/afYv49pALJk/hqdefault.jpg" height="300px" width="300px"> </td>

        </td>
        <td class="n">
            <img class="animate" src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/afYv49pALJk/hqdefault.jpg" height="300px" width="300px"> </td>

        </td>
        <td class="n">
            <img class="animate" src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/afYv49pALJk/hqdefault.jpg" height="300px" width="300px"> </td>
    </tr>

</table>
<script src="task1.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Как реализовать через js,что бы при клику по картинка пропадал фон(серый), снова при клику появлялся

Comment: можно на одном css сделать такое - такой код устроит? правда 2 лишних элемента придется добавить :)

Comment: вы добавляете/удаляете класс у `selectedTd`. Но этот элемент просто объявлен и никакое значение ему не присвоено `let selectedTd;`. Вопрос чему вы присваиваете стили?

Comment: вы передаете в функцию `highlight(target);` но в самой функции с параметром не работаете, а обращаетесь к `selectedTd` который у вас неопределен

Comment: * Там в разметке два лишних `</td>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ваш код не срабатывает только из-за того, что сравниваете `if (target.tagName == 'img')` — tagName всегда пишется большими буквами) Заменить на `== "IMG"` и заработает.

Но вообще-то `while (target != this)` тоже не нужен в этом случае: Внутри img не бывает других элементов. Если на что-то кликнули, то это или img или нет, без вариантов.

```js
let table = document.getElementById("tableS");

table.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  if (e.target.tagName == "IMG") {
    e.target.classList.toggle("active");
  }
});
```

```css
img.animate {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  opacity: 0.25;
}

img.animate.active {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<table id="tableS">
  <tr>
    <td class="n">
      <img class="animate" src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/afYv49pALJk/hqdefault.jpg">
    </td>

    <td class="n">
      <img class="animate" src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/afYv49pALJk/hqdefault.jpg">
    </td>

    <td class="n">
      <img class="animate" src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/afYv49pALJk/hqdefault.jpg">
    </td>
  </tr>

</table>
```

Comment: Спасибо, но как реализовать, чтобы при клике на первую картинку, а потом клик на вторую, фон не появлялся на первой

Comment: @Tekk Он и не появляется на первой... куда кликнули, тот и выделяется о_О

Comment: я имел в виду, чтобы когда я кликаю на первую, потом на вторую, чтобы active не скидувалося с первой

Comment: @Tekk Можно проверять, `if (e.target.classList.contains("active") { e.targe.classList.remove("active"); } else { e.target.classList.add("active") }` — но вместо этого, существует готовый метод `classList.toggle()` - добавил в ответ.